# UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "UTF-8") not successful

Tags: utf8-decode

My task is to insert data from a java program through PHP to database.
Here are my codes in java:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I added `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); in my PHP file`
However, the database still shows something like ååŸŽ5åº§2æ¨ and ä¸Šé‹ª .

I tested the variables in nameValuePair by 
`Log.e("TEST", name + " " + propName + " " + roomLoc + " " + roomType + " " + contact + " " + email + " " + rentStart + " " + rentEnd + " ");`
The values are shown properly.

My database can show words in utf8, tested by using pure PHP request.

May I know how I can have those data in utf8 in my database?